# Reading a file chunk by chunk in QT 4.3.3

Tags: c++, file, io, qt

I have following  code in QT in

```
// myEditor.h
class myEditor : QScintilla {
    public:
        readFile();
};

#include "myEditor.h"
// myEditor.cc
myEditor::readFile() {
   FILE* fp = fopen("mynew.v","r"):
   QTextStream ts(fp, QIODevice::ReadOnly);
   /* reading the  text stream  buffer by buffer
   bufferSize is calculated using following formula
   2 to power(k) *  n  =  2 to power 31*
   where n is  size of each block in linux filesystem*/

   int bufferSize =(1024* 1024)/2;
   do {
      QString s = ts.read(bufferSize);
      append(s);
    } while(!ts.atEnd());
}
```

I calculated the bufferSize as per comments .It will be helpful if someone can review the code and let me know if there are issues.

Comment: for comment 1 , legacy code was like that but it crashed when size of file is greater than 500 MB  and we have such use cases .

Comment: For comment3 , I am not sure whether QFile will open .gz file

Comment: Hi, because the comments are for the answer, they should be placed there, not underneath the question. Are you trying to display 500MB of text in `QScintilla`? I'm sure it wasn't designed for this. As for gzip files, `QFile`, by itself, doesn't handle (de)compression, but neither does `fopen()`

Answer (score 2):

As you're storing the whole result into memory anyway for display in a text editor (so you're not expecting to load hundreds of MB of text), why not just use what Qt provides to read the [entire file into a string in one call](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17149454/reading-entire-file-to-qstring)?

It's probably more than enough optimized for general purpose usage. Displaying the entire result in the editor might also be faster than constantly appending parts.

I also see that you're using the C API for opening the file (which is never closed) and then passing it to Qt. Qt has `QFile` for this, as shown in the link mentioned above.